# ¿Por que no me funciona sweetalert2, pero si un alert normal?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

tengo un problema con sweetalert2, estoy haciendo un piedra papel tijeras, pero al querer utilizarla para mostrar la elección de la maquina esta no aparece, pero si en vez de utilizar el sweet utilizo un alert normal este funciona

```
function maquina() {
    let numero = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
    console.log(`Numero de la maquina ${numero}`);
    if(numero == 1){
        Swal.fire('La Maquina escogio piedra!')
    }else if(numero == 2){
        Swal.fire('La Maquina escogio Papel!')
    }else if(numero == 3){
        Swal.fire('La Maquina escogio Tijeras!')
    }

        return numero;
 }
```

Comment: Puedes consultar la documentación de la instalación https://sweetalert2.github.io/#download, la sintaxis parece estar bien. Igual deberías mostrar el código para ver mas detalles.

Comment: Hola si, pero en mi codigo la utilizo antes de eso y si funciona

Comment: Pega el codigo completo asi lo vemos

Comment: Esto es un comentario, no una respuesta :)

Comment: @MarioPosada no me permite ya que es muy largo

Comment: Recuerda que debes insertar un [repro] (énfasis en _mínimo_). No es necesario que pegues todo el código, en todo caso, agrega más descripción a tu pregunta (sin agregar ruido).

Answer (score 2):

@Tiago, como comenta @Mario Posada, al no ver el código pareciera que no estás llamando a la libreria, anexo respuesta con tu código, el mismo funciona adecuadamente.

```js
function maquina() {
  let numero = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
  console.log(`Numero de la maquina ${numero}`);
  if (numero == 1) {

    //alert('La Maquina escogio piedra!')
    Swal.fire('La Maquina escogio piedra!')
  } else if (numero == 2) {
    //alert('La Maquina escogio Papel!')
    Swal.fire('La Maquina escogio Papel!')
  } else if (numero == 3) {
    //alert('La Maquina escogio Tijeras!')
    Swal.fire('La Maquina escogio Tijeras!')
  }

  return numero;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <h3>Prueba de Sweetalert2</h3>
  <hr>
  <button onclick="maquina()">Ejecuta Script</button>

</body>

</html>
```